# How to use api.ai speech recognition in my service

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, dialogflow-es

As I was learning how to use [api.ai](https://api.ai/), I created a service that accepts text and replies with some text. But I observed that I can use my voice, and it will recognize what I say, see the microphone in the iamge:[image]
Now I want to use this feature in my service. I mean instead of taking text from the user, I want to take an audio file and [api.ai](https://api.ai/) recognizes speech in that file and sends response to the user accordingly.
If anyone could help, I will be grateful.

Comment: Start by reading their docs? They have a full walkthrough. https://api.ai/docs/getting-started/basics

Comment: Actually I did, but I am still not figuring it out!

Comment: There's a full walkthrough, including complete sample code. If that doesn't do the trick, it might be time to hire a developer.

Answer (score 2):

I developed an application using action AI and it's working fine. I referred the below sample application for development. [https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-android-client][1]

let me know if you have any query after referring this code.

Comment: But this is for android.. I want to create a desktop application, not a mobile application. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, since API.AI speech recognition is going to be deprecated (or already deprecated).

1. Use some of the integrations (e.g. the Google Assistant integration)
2. Or use another api for your speech recognition (like the [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/))

Comment: But google speech API is not free. I am trying the first solution

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely the simplest solution. Microsoft has a service with 5000 free transactions per month. https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/pricing/details/cognitive-services/speech-api/

Comment: Google Speech Recognition is also free for <60 min of speech / month.